# How to share full screen image android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am displaying image in the view pager by fetching from the server.I am not displaying the full screen image.I have added the feature to share the image via email or many other options.

**code to share image**

```
imageView = (TouchImageView) viewpager.findViewWithTag(viewpager
            .getCurrentItem());
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,
            "description", null);
    uri = Uri.parse(path);
    Intent send_report = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Give Me That Picture");
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "cool picture");
    send_report.setType("text/plain");
    send_report.setType("image/png");
    startActivityForResult(
    Intent.createChooser(send_report, "Choose an Email client"), 77);
```

But the image which is shared is not a full screen image.But i want to share the actual size image.Please help me out on this.

**UPDATE**
**view pager adapter**

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        PhotoViewAttacher attacher;
        PhotoViewAttacher pic;

        private DisplayImageOptions options;
        private List<Wallpaper> IMAGES_LIST = AppController.getInstance()
                .getPrefManger().getAllImages();




        public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.item_pager_image, container, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            pos = position;
            imageView = (TouchImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            // pic=new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
            imageView.setTag(position);

            imageView.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("hello", "sinfle");
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(r);
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    done.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gimmy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(r, 5 * 1000);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("hello", "donl");

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });

            share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showShareDialog();
                }

            });

            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.loading);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                    IMAGES_LIST.get(position).getUrl(), imageView, options,
                    new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                FailReason failReason) {
                            String message = null;
                            switch (failReason.getType()) {
                            case IO_ERROR:
                                message = "Input/Output error";
                                break;
                            case DECODING_ERROR:
                                message = "Image can't be decoded";
                                break;
                            case NETWORK_DENIED:
                                message = "Downloads are denied";
                                break;
                            case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                                message = "Out Of Memory error";
                                break;
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                message = "Unknown error";
                                break;
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }
                    });

            container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGES_LIST.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it not a full screen image"? In terms of display or resolution?

Comment: Image is bot visible on full screen? it is having margin from top & bottom so it is displayed in center of the screen. @shkschneider

Comment: You should share the whole image you fetched from the server. Not the smaller one you put in an imageview.

Comment: You should show us how do you get an image and where do you store  it before applying to imageView

Comment: The only problem i can think of here is ImageView, it has some sizes and can have some scaleType on it's own, you should just cache this image and take it from cache to achieve your goal

Comment: How to take it from cahce? @NikMyers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the cache of the current image in view pager then you will get the view which is being displayed on view pager with margins.You need to download the image from the server.Get the url of current displayed image in view pager & download the image from the server.This will solve your problem.

Comment: but why he need to download it twice i he had in cache already... i can't get it

Answer (score 2):

You've already set `cacheOnDisk(true)`, so now you want to take an image from it by:

```
File cachedImage = imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(imageUrl);
if (cachedImage.exists()) {
    /// get your image from file
}
```